# Requirejs optimizer. Integrating my all module in a single page

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have created multiple modules based on Backbone and Require.js.
Each module has its own main.js for require.config which load its dependencies and starts the module.

Now, i want to integrate my modules in a single page. What is the best way to include all my main.js for each module for a single page.

Comment: create an app with iframes. use iframe to load modules.

Comment: Well, requirement is in the same lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248495/loading-entire-modules-at-once-using-backbone-js-multiple-views-models-collec/19254766#19254766